# Table just for grouping

Tags: mysql, database-design

Is it a common case to have a table with a single column for the purpose of grouping rows in another table?

I'm inserting data in batches and I want to have an autoincrement key for each batch to be able to group data based on generated id.

Concretely I want to get from this

```
A
id, x, y, b_id
id PRIMARY KEY
b_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES B.id

B
id, timestamp
id PRIMARY KEY

SELECT count(*) as number, B.timestamp FROM A inner join B on A.b_id=B.id
                     where A.x='value' and A.y='value'
                     group by B.id;
```

to

```
A
id, x, y, timestamp, b_id
id PRIMARY KEY
b_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES B.id

B
id
id PRIMARY KEY

SELECT count(*) as number, A.timestamp FROM A
                         where A.x='value' and A.y='value'
                         group by A.b_id, A.timestamp;
```

So basically move timestamp to B (denormalize) and use foreign key only for grouping. I want to avoid having join only for the timestamp placed in B. Tables are quite big (60M of rows) and join is very slow. If I still filter on A and have foreign key only for grouping then that would speed up things a lot.

Concretely, I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Are you talking about architectural changes to the tables or asking the best way to query?  This question is really unclear.   Please provide your table logic or an ERD.  What business problem are you trying to solve?  As a general answer to your question, is it common, it depends entirely on the situation.

Comment: I'm talking about table design, to improve query performance. I receive a batch of records periodically. I might get two batches at the same time (in parallel), so I cannot differ between batches only on timestamp, that is why I added another table (column) which has autoincrement value, when I get a batch I insert into grouping table (B), I get b_id and I insert batch of records in table (A) with same b_id. Then I can group by b_id and count how many times A.x and A.y satisfy condition PER BATCH. If I move timestamp to A, does it make sense table B to exist with only id (index) column?

Comment: Ok.  I think I see what you are getting at.  In most scenarios, offloading that information to another table won't help performance since you are still going to need a reference to that table.  The reference would have the same result as an index though.  To improve read performance on the single table, consider a nonclustered (secondary in mysql) index on the batch_id.  This won't help write performance on inserts though so you will need to balance the need to read fast or write fast.

Comment: But I should be able to gain performance, right? As I'm not doing the join any longer? And isn't it enough that batch_id is a foreign key (already indexed)?

Comment: Read performance yes.  Write performance, no.  It will actually be slower. If there is no data in the second table that needs to be returned, don't do the join.  There's no reason to join if you aren't returning anything.  Yes, the foreign key will act as an index so no need if you already have it.  If you are planning on dropping the secondary table and foreign key, I would add a secondary index on the column for read performance.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Nope, I cannot drop them as I need that column for grouping, I'm just moving the timestamp from one table to another. I'm keeping batch_id because it is unique and autoincrement, which I need for batches.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.  There's no reason to keep the table at all just for grouping.  You can group the data off column in the first table.  If that's all the table is for, it's redundant.

Comment: But I need unique, autoincrement value for the whole batch. How can I do that? My current approach is: insert into first table, batch_id is generated, insert the whole batch into second table with the same batch_id. If I don't do  it like this I have to keep track in my app and that's not what I want. Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: There's no reason to 'keep track' of much outside the database.  All you have to do is to a check on the table for the highest batch_id and have the app increment it for you(SELECT MAX ID + 1 FROM TABLE) should be a very light operation if you have your indexes set.  Another option is just store the highest batch id in a second table and update it only each time you run the batch.  In that case, I would want to make sure there was only one record in that table to aid performance.  No foreign key needed. Using the database to increment your id's is not always the best approach.

Comment: I'm not sure what will I get with that approach? In my case I'm performing insert and retrieving the last generated batch_id. Additionally, I'm having multiple producers running in parallel. This could make a race condition (e.g. two producers get same batch_id and insert with batch_id+1). Maybe I could solve this with transactions. But anyway, I don't see how is that better than my current approach with one extra table+column?

Comment: You never mentioned multiple users running batches.  I was thinking a more automated approach (one server to the other).  In that case, the option to utilize a single record table should be used to eliminate the possibility of race conditions.  Unless you need to store secondary information about the batch itself, (i.e. the user running, the source host machine etc.) I still wouldn't advocate it.  On the other hand, if you would like to record 'batch' specific information, then the approach you are using makes sense.

Comment: One other possibility which would actually perform better on inserts is to look into using a GUID based id instead of an incrementing ID.  That would eliminate the possibility of race conditions and would also limit the need for an extra round trip to the database.  This would actually work great whether there was a secondary table or not.

Answer (score 2):

Is it common to mark rows with a batch number? Yes it is. In accounting contexts I have seen this used widely for audit and reconciliation purposes.

Is having a separate table to store batch-related values a good idea? Yes it is. Good practice in relational DB design is to have one table per entity type. Since your problem domain recognises "batch" as a concept, with its own values, it should have a table.

Should this table use an autoincrement column? Well, this is very much an implementation detail. Does your problem domain allow for gaps, negatives, re-use after delete, out of order values etc. etc? Does your DBMS software guarantee the necessary features? If so then, sure, go for it. If not, write your own generator with the needed guarantees.

Will denormalising timestamp from the "batch" table to the "data" table improve performance? Can't say. It will make the data table wider, which should cause more IO. There may be enough spare space in each page that this doesn't happen, however. If all the data, or at least the woking set, fits in memory, this consideration is void.

If there are good indexes in place and they are being used I'd guess denormalisation won't change much. You could try rewriting the query. Sometimes if the optimizer starts from a different place it ends up with a different plan. Put `select..from a group by b_id` in a subquery, then join that to `b` to get the timestamp.

You need to understand where the time is consumed and address that. And of course test, test, test.